# in_array() returns wrong values?

Tags: php, arrays

I found a strange error in `in_array()` PHP function.

Next code returns **`TRUE`** but it's wrong value. Anyone can told my what I do wrong?

```
<?php
var_dump(in_array(0, array('a', 'ab', 'abc')));
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81013d156637fd06557b632f102d52f72d0f9d77

Of course I know that I can execute `in_array(0, array('a', 'ab', 'abc'), true)` but why without this `true` this function isn't working good.

Comment: Because of PHP type juggling. Without the parameter strict to be true PHP does a loosely comparison.

Comment: That looks very similar to this comment in the php documentation.  Similar issue.  Anybody know what's going on? http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#114117

Comment: [Spot the difference](https://3v4l.org/CmF6h)

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) `Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.`

Comment: You have to set `TYPE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array` you have to set `type`

Syntax:

```
in_array(search,array,type);

var_dump(in_array(0, array('a', 'ab', 'abc'), true));
```

**Note:** If the search parameter is a string and the type parameter is set to **TRUE**, the search is **case-sensitive**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2):

You have to set it strict

```
var_dump(in_array(0, array('a', 'ab', 'abc'), true));
```